# JavaFX login screen will not switch scenes

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I hav a JavaFx project that uses a login screen to to switch pages for accredited users. However, when my login button is pressed with the correct credentials in the the textfield and passwordfield, nothing happens, no errors are given either. Can someone help me figure out why there's not a scene switch occurring?

Here is my FXML file for my login page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.mall.HelloController">
    <left>
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="350.0" style="-fx-background-color: #6D5090;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="92.0" layoutY="244.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="The Shopping Mall">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                    </font>
                </Text>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </left>
    <right>
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="415.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <TextField id="username" fx:id="usernameField" layoutX="101.0" layoutY="208.0" onAction="#login" promptText="Username" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #0598ff; -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;" />
                <PasswordField id="password" fx:id="passwordField" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="261.0" onAction="#login" promptText="Password" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-border-color: #0598ff; -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;" />
                <Button fx:id="loginButton" layoutX="129.0" layoutY="335.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#login" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="90.0" style="-fx-background-color: #6D5090;" text="Login" textFill="WHITE" />
                <Text fill="#6d5090" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="129.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="User Login">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="22.0" />
                    </font>
                </Text>
                <Button layoutX="320.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exit" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="30.0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent;">
                    <graphic>
                        <Text fill="#6d5090" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="X">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="16.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Text>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
                <Label fx:id="errorLabel" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="402.0" text="Incorrect Login. Try Again" textFill="#ff4d4d" visible="false" />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
    </right>
</BorderPane>
```

Here is my controller class:

```
package com.example.mall;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class HelloController {
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;


    @FXML
    private Label errorLabel;

    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;

    @FXML
    private TextField usernameField;

    @FXML
    private void exit(ActionEvent event) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    

   @FXML
    public void login(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

           HashMap<String,String> logininfo = new HashMap<String,String>();

           logininfo.put("customer","customer123");
           logininfo.put("staff","staff123");
           logininfo.put("ceo","ceo123");
           String username;
           username = usernameField.getText();
       System.out.println(username);
           String password;
           password = String.valueOf(passwordField.getText());

       System.out.println(password);

         if (event.getSource()==loginButton){
             //if(logininfo.containsKey(username)){
                 System.out.println("Switching scenesaaaaaaa");
                    if(logininfo.get(username).equals(password)){
                        System.out.println("Switching scenes");
                        switchScene(event, "ShoppingInterface.fxml");
                    }

            //}
         }

    }


    public void switchScene(ActionEvent event,String fxmlFileName) throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Switching to scene: " + fxmlFileName);
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlFileName));
            Scene newScene = new Scene(loader.load());
            Stage primaryStage = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

            primaryStage.setScene(newScene);
            primaryStage.show();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));

    }
}
```

And here is my main file:

```
package com.example.mall;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UserLogin extends Application {

    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED.UNDECORATED);

        root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event){
                xOffset = event.getScreenX();
                yOffset = event.getScreenY();
            }

        });

        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event){
                stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset );
                stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset );

            }
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

I've made sure my onAction is linked to the correct method name, and I even tried using print statements throughout the process of entering the username and password but even those statements don't print within the terminal.

Comment: I wonder if calling `getClass()` on your controller class rather than your `Application` subclass is part of the problem.

Comment: Is Login() executed if you click the button? Can you put a system out in the method to check this? System.out.println("username="+username) please, because you don't see the s.out if username is empty.

Comment: And please remove "if (event.getSource()==loginButton)". This is guaranteed bot good. You could compare with ".equals()", but just don't. It is not necessary.

Comment: you have `onAction="#login"` in TextField, PasswordField and Button try to only have it for the button

Comment: The code you posted here works as expected for me. I copied and pasted the two classes and FXML verbatim, ran the `UserLogin` application, and when I logged in it output the lines from the `System.out.println(...)` statements and tried to load `ShoppingInterface.fxml`.

Comment: @Anon Why on earth would that make any difference?

Comment: @DavidWeber `==` and `.equals(...)` are completely equivalent in this scenario (both are redundant though as they are necessarily true).

Comment: @James_D just as I said: "but just don't" (compare the button). "It is not necessary". To the other topic: Comparing references with == is not a good idea IMO, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @DavidWeber Agreed on "just don't". But I disagree completely with "You could compare with `.equals(...)`". In this case, if `.equals(...)` was overridden so it was different to `==`, then `==` would give the correct logic, and `.equals(...)` would give the incorrect logic. So if you did do a comparison, you should do it with `==`.

Comment: You are right with that, that's why I said "unless you know exactly what you are doing". :)

Comment: @DavidWeber I tried using print statements within the method but nothing prints inside the terminal once the button is pressed

Comment: @James_D I just copied everything over into a new project file and it runs fine as you said. Sorry for what seems to be a lack of effort on my part, I'm a student and still learning how to troubleshoot my own errors!

Comment: Do **not** use the `Initializable` interface. It has been superseded by an injection approach, as of JavaFX 2.1. See the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html).

Comment: @TristanD Actually This is a well-written question, because it contains everything needed to copy, paste, and run the application. That's how I was able to determine there was nothing wrong with the code you posted (so presumably something was wrong with the configuration, or possibly the original project needed a "clean and rebuild"). I don't know why so many people posted comments with random, incorrect guesses on here when you provided everything needed to try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for future readers:**

The solution was to copy everything over into a new project. After that it worked. The mistake was caused by the questioneer himself.

Credits to @James_D for figuring this out.